# Effect of increasing parallelism on throughput

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I ran a job first with Parallelism 1 and then with Parallelism 3. With Parallelism=1, the kafka source was reading records at rate ~500 records per second. With Parallelism=3, the throughput got divided among the three parallelisms, each reading approximately ~150 records per second. Note that the source is publishing records at a much higher rate (~1000 records per second).

Is this expected? I would imagine the throughput to increase with parallelism, but it is remaining the same. I checked the `Backpressure` status on the source, it was `High`.

Screenshots for reference:

Parallelism 1:
[image: Parallelism 1]

Parallelism 3:
[image: Parallelism 3]

Comment: Can you add which version of flink you are using and how many partitions on kafka topic

Comment: When you see the backpressure of an operator in a Flink workflow, it's showing (via sampling) how often the operator can't send a record to the next operator in the workflow graph. So if your source has high backpressure, then what's the next operator that is unable to keep up?

Comment: You need to find and eliminate the cause of the backpressure, then the throughput can improve.

Comment: My suggestion is to run your job with only the Kafka Source to discard backpressure.

Comment: Can you please add more information? Which flink version are you using? How is the topology looking? How many partitions does the input topic have? Are you using exactly once? If so, what are you checkpointing settings?