# Increasing Parallelism in Flink decreases/splits the overall throughput

Tags: apache-flink, throughput

My problem is exactly similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601740/effect-of-increasing-parallelism-on-throughput) except that Backpressure in my application is coming as "OK".

I thought the problem was with my local machine not having enough configuration, so I created a 72 core Windows machine, where I am reading data from Kafka, processing it in Flink and then writing the output back in Kafka. I have checked, writing into Kafka Sink is not causing any issues.

All I am looking for are the areas that may be causing a split in Throughput among task slots by increasing parallelism?

Flink Version: 1.7.2

Scala version: 2.12.8

Kafka version: 2.11-2.2.1

Java version: 1.8.231

Working of application: Data is coming from Kafka (1 partition) which is deserialized by Flink (throughput here is 5k/sec). Then the deserialized message is passed through basic schema validation (Throughput here is 2k/sec).
Even after increasing the parallelism to 2, throughput at Level 1 (deserializing stage) remains same and **doesn't increase two fold** as per expectation.

I understand, without the code, it is difficult to debug so I am asking for the points which you can suggest for this problem, so that I can go back to my code and try that.

Comment: Can you please add more information?
Which flink version are you using?
How is the topology looking?
How many partitions does the input topic have?
Are you using exactly once? If so, what are you checkpointing settings?

Comment: a) Flink 1.7.2 
b) Kafka 2.11-2.2.1
c) As of now, we are just deserializing the records coming from Kafka (Throughput coming at that stage is around 5k/sec), then we are just doing a basic schema validation (here speed reduces to 2k/sec).
d) We are using 1 Kafka partition for our input topic. 
e) We have the functionalities of exactly once, checkpointing etc in our code but they are disabled currently because we are not getting high numbers at the basic stage of processing. 

Problem is increasing parallelism is just dividing the overall throughput between task slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We are using 1 Kafka partition for our input topic.

If you want to process data in parallel, you actually need to read data in parallel.

There are certain requirements to read data in parallel. The most important once are that the source is able to actually split the data into smaller work chunks. For example, if you read from a file system, you have multiple files, or the system subdivides the files into splits. For Kafka, this necessarily means that **you have to have more partitions**. Ideally, you have at least as many partitions than you have max consumer parallelism.

The 5k/s seems to be the maximum throughput that you can achieve on one partition. You can also calculate the number of partitions by the maximum throughput you want to achieve. If you need to achieve 50k/s, you need at least 10 partitions. You should use more to also catch up in case of reprocessing or failure recovery.

Another way to distribute the work is to add a [manual shuffle step](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/#physical-partitioning). That means, if you keep the single input partition, you would still only reach 5k/s, but after that the work is actually redistributed and processed in parallel, such that you will not see a huge decline in your throughput afterwards. After a shuffle operation, work is somewhat evenly distributed among the parallel downstream tasks.

Comment: Thanks Arvid... I checked my Kafka partition (after increasing it from 1 to 10). Throughput has increased, but there is still some issue with my Kafka/Data as data is not being distributed to all partitions. Now I am going to focus on Kafka + Data rather than Flink code.

Comment: To distribute data in Kafka, there are two options. If you don't set any key, data should be distributed in round robin; that's the easy mode. If you need a key, because you want events having that key to appear in the correct order, make sure that your key has enough values (e.g., no boolean flag) and values are distributed somewhat evenly (e.g., surnames are often skewed). If all fails, you can also set partition explicitly, but I'd use that as a last resort.

Comment: Furthermore, the number of partitions should have a good room for the future as you cannot change that easily in Kafka later on. So if 10 partitions is enough for now, pick at least 20. With a bit of luck, that already solves your issue with undistributed partitions. However, there is also a slim chance that it makes the current situation worse, as Flink sources currently pick random partitions and if you end up with two heavy partitions of a skewed distribution ending up at the same source instance, it becomes the bottleneck.